# ACPI PCC probe failed while trying to install Freya

Tags: kernel, acpi

I'm trying to install Freya alongside Windows 10 on my new PC. It's an Alienware X51 R3 (i7-6700K, GTX 960). I've been using and installing elementary OS in different machines for a couple of years, and now I'm having some trouble to initiate the image written onto an USB. As soon as the USB boots and I choose "Install Elementary OS Freya", this message appears:

[0.742776] ACPI PCC probe failed

I've tried different USB keys and I've also seen many people having similar problems. Is anyone there who can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you boot on your usb stick and you are presented with this screen:
[image: grub chooser]

Press 'e' and search for a line like this
[image: after pressing e]

and put before quiet splash `nomodeset`.

If that fixes your issue, it is graphics related, and you might have to repeat this process even after the installation until you installed the correct drivers.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the `nomodeset` boot option permanently,

Open terminal and run,

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

then add `nomodeset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Then save and exit.

After that you need to update `grub`

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Nomodeset is not an real solution, it just disables the driver. It should only be used temporarily until you've configured your drivers correctly.