# Can't get passed splash screen

Tags: grub

So tried to install elementary OS via a USB. I initially tried to install it alongside Ubuntu. This was all fine but then I received a "fatal error" concerning the grub. I couldn't click anything so I shut the laptop down and tried again, this time I just chose to wipe the hard drive and install elementary OS exclusively.

This went fine and I wasn't presented with a grub error. The installation finished and my screen went blank. My cursor appeared and it started blinking at intervals. I couldn't do anything so I rebooted. Now all I get is the elementary OS splash screen and sometimes a copyright notice from a Peter Dalvin. I fear I may have wrecked my laptop, since I can't do anything.

Laptop: Lenovo G50-45 8 gigs ram 900g hd. AMD Radeon A4 Graphics Quad core CPU

Comment: see http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2517/acpi-pcc-probe-failed-while-trying-to-install-freya if useful